# What elements to use for Google Inbox list

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Using [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/) what elements could be used to make a list of items (with a card that pop-ups when clicked), such as the email list in Google Inbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up using was the [iron-collapse](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-collapse?view=demo:demo/index.html) element inside a card (I mostly use [paper-material](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-material?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-material) for all card-like-styles).

Inbox uses several tricks that focus attention to the selected card/email, neither of which I ended up applying. But it should be easy to elevate the focused card and expand its left-right widths.

Answer (score 0):

The following elements may be useful to you.

- [paper-listbox](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-listbox) may be useful for representing the list of mails
- [paper-dialog](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dialog) can be used to display the pop-up which should appear on clicking

Comment: I'll look into using the paper-dialog for the expanded card. Might be tricky though but if I get it working I'll mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Chrome extention [Polymer Ready](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/polymer-ready/aaifiopbmiecbpladpjaoemohhfjcbdk?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) which tells you what elements a page is using. You should be able to run in on Google Inbox to see how they created it

Comment: Cool, had not seen that before. I'll check it out -thanks!